# Red light therapy LED spotlight

Tags: led, surface-mount

What's the easiest way to mount a bunch of surface mount LEDs into an array or spotlight?

There are a bunch of very interesting new papers on red light therapy for a variety of conditions. I want to experiment with it. The most beneficial spectrum is around 650nm. I can't seem to find any bulbs that come ready made with the ~650nm LEDs in them. If you know otherwise, please speak up.

So I figure I can get thirty or so of these Phillips "deep red" LEDs, mount them parallel, and connect to a suitable power supply:

[Philips Lumileds LXM3-PD01](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Philips-Lumileds/LXM3-PD01/?qs=SB5DQgYJm0lu6qaylev%252bTw%3d%3d)

I'd like to avoid having to solder them on to stripboard or something like that. Partly because I've never worked with SMD and haven't soldered in many years. Can anyone think of an easy way to mount them?

There are a bunch of LED spotlights that come with white LEDs already installed:

[LED Spot Lights](http://www.miniinthebox.com/spot-bulbs_c4931)

Is there a way to get the fixtures without the LEDs? Should it be easy to remove the white LEDs and refit the Phillips red LEDs? I don't have any experience with such things.

Comment: Peopel will sell them to you mounted on "Stars"- for extra money of course. Such as here http://shop.stevesleds.com/Philips-Luxeon-ES-Deep-Red-3-Watt-LEDs-Luxeon-ES-Deep-Red.htm People who sell mounted LEDs may be willing to custom mount some for you. Street lights often use arrays of LEDs and such MAY be suitable for mounting your LEDs. As others have noted, heat dissipation needs proper attention.

Comment: Those stars mounted on heatsinks with some paste seem like the way to go.

Comment: The stars also need heatsinking - but it's a lot easier to connect them mechanically than the LEDs themselves. Luxeon publish some excellent documents on LED thermal issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, you can mount them on a circuit board just like everything else.
The Phillips LEDs you link are meant to be mounted on a circuit board that is well cooled (heatsink and/or fan) as these are high-power, specifically ~750mW for red.

There are similar LEDs called Luxeon Rebel which look strikingly similar to those phillips ones which you can buy breakout boards that don't have any of them mounted already.  I believe they are sold by sparkfun.com

Since your application sounds like it is targeted at a specific area, the solution needs to be compact.  You'll need to design a circuit board and get it fabricated.  You'll need to be able to draw all the heat away from the board since you'll be keeping it on for 15 minutes.  This means a wicked heatsink and a beastly fan which mean this won't be the most silent device.

Comment: Philips Lumileds is the manufacturer of the Luxeon brand.

Comment: Okay, I thought like, "Hey, they might be the same thing buddy"  Thanks!

Comment: The idea here is to have thirty or so in a fairly tight array held very close to the skin for about fifteen minutes. You want to blast the tissue with 650nm light. Those breakout boards don't look practical for such an array. I think a household box fan blowing on the array might be good enough for cooling? But then I don't know that some stripboard is a good enough mounting considering the potential heat.

Comment: You will not be using strip board for this.  
The application honestly requires a custom circuit board.  Professionally fabricated, you can use OSHpark or a better place if you want.  The biggest concern for this is power, you need to be able to supply enough current at 2.1v and then be able to evacuate all the heat produced.  Its going to need a wicked heatsink and a killer fan since this sounds like a fairly compact application. And for 15 minutes, yea you need a beastly fan and heatsink.

Comment: The power supply wouldn't be on the board. An external box would supply DC voltage. I don't understand why a custom circuit would be necessary. I can understand the need for heat sinks, but I don't see what's custom about that. I just need to figure out a way to get the LEDs dissipating heat.

Comment: Well you can't find a board that already exists that is fit for such an array, you need to make your own then.  Regardless of where the power supply is, you are going to need a heatsink and a fan.  30 of these things will be dissipating around 45W, I could run a computer on that.

Comment: I'm wondering about wires mounted in a block of ceramic. I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work. Anyway, I don't think the heat is such a big deal. I mean, a 30W bulb incandescent isn't too hot to handle. Also I think a good deal of the wattage in this case is light, not heat.

Comment: Are you trying to make this on the cheap?

Comment: Not especially cheap, I just don't understand at all how having a simple set of parallel mount points and some heatsinks requires a custom circuit. I fail to understand any advantage over other options. The existing LED spotlight fixtures actually look perfect, which is why I asked if it's crazy to buy one and rip out the white LEDs.

Comment: Yea, it is crazy.  White LEDs have a different forward voltage, not only that but those bulbs are interfaced with mains which can kill you.  Nobody in their right mind would mess with that unless they knew exactly what they are doing.  I assume you looked at all other buying options but none were good enough which is why you came here.  Look you are going to be sinking quite a bit of current and nothing is fit for such an array that already exists, therefore it has to be custom if you want it to exist. Its a high-power application, you need to dissipate the heat

Comment: They're not interfaced with mains. They're set up to connect to an external DC power supply. 45 watts of power, only a fraction of which is heat, does not seem like too major a problem to me with adequate heatsinks. I still don't understand what about the circuit needs to be custom. It's just LEDs spaced a bit apart on rails. The custom circuit would be effectively stripboard with heatsinks?

Comment: @sammysamsam Where would you be getting the information that for an LED, "*only a fraction of which is heat*"? A typical high power LED has a luminous efficiency of the order of 15%, give or take. Regular LEDs can be as low as 5 to 10%. This means around 85% of the power fed to the LED ends up as heat. One could argue that 85% is a *fraction*, but it is not a *small fraction*. The most recent Cree high efficiency LEDs, which are more efficient than the Luxeons, boast 25% (i.e. 75% is heat). See [this](http://www.ledsmagazine.com/articles/2005/05/fact-or-fiction-leds-don-t-produce-heat.html).

Comment: The reason LEDs run so much cooler than e.g. incandescent is not because losses to heat are small, but because the much higher relative efficiency means the ratio of light to heat is much higher.  (And also because high temperature isn't a necessary part of the physics)

Comment: @BenVoigt can you give me a link to the physics?  I would love to study and learn it.

Comment: @ShannonStrutz: All I meant is that incandescent bulbs glow by making the filament hot.  You can't operate a low-temperature incandescent bulb regardless of the required light output.  (The high temperatures are isolated to the filament as much as possible, of course, but heating is a desired and required part of incandescent lighting)

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not questioning you, i just saw somebody who knows something I don't and was curious.